# how to get the latest version number of a package on PyPI?

Tags: python, pypi

Is it possible, using `pip` or any other command line tool, to get the latest version number of a package on PyPI **without downloading it first**?

The web page of packages in PyPI will usually provide this information, so I'm assuming there's a chance it's available otherwise.

My goal is to be able to compare the latest version on PyPI and compare it with other sources (like the latest tag in a git repository for example) to detect if it's out-of-date or any other sort of version conflict.

Comment: What do you mean "get latest version" without downloading it?  How is this different from `pip install package`?

Comment: Do you mean you want to know the version number of the latest version of the package?

Comment: Yolk can list versions for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888027/python-and-pip-list-all-versions-of-a-package-thats-available

Comment: Check out https://github.com/alexmojaki/outdated

Comment: @rahmu Say you want the latest version of the `certifi` PyPI package, you can try this : `pythonPackage=certifi;curl -Ls https://pypi.org/pypi/$pythonPackage/json | jq -r .info.version` Of course, you can replace the package `certifi` by the name of the PyPI package you want :)