# Heroku: No matching distribution found for PIL==1.1.7

Tags: django, heroku, pip

I am trying to push on my Heroku app and getting error while installing PIL on server, I have tried by tweaking my requirements.txt as given below

```
Django==1.4.5
Fabric==1.4.3
--allow-all-external
--allow-unverified PIL
PIL==1.1.7
#Pillow==2.3.0
```

Also tried by adding parameters at start of requirements.txt as given below:

```
--allow-all-external
--allow-unverified PIL
Django==1.4.5
Fabric==1.4.3
PIL==1.1.7
#Pillow==2.3.0
```

this is failing with error:

```
remote:   InsecurePlatformWarning
remote:        Downloading Django-1.4.5.tar.gz (7.7MB)
remote:        Collecting Fabric==1.4.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:        Downloading Fabric-1.4.3.tar.gz (221kB)
remote:        Collecting PIL==1.1.7 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
remote:   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL==1.1.7 (
om -r requirements.txt (line 5)) (from versions: )
remote: No matching distribution found for PIL==1.1.7 (from -r requirements.tx
(line 5))
remote:
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to my-test-app.
remote:
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/) instead of PIL. [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/) is not maintained and has not had a new release since 2009. Pillow is a maintained fork.

Comment: ok.. I removed PIL and facing same error for newrelic==1.7.0.31 in requirements file.

Comment: New relic [version 1.7.0.31](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/release-notes/agent-release-notes/python-release-notes/python-agent-17031) is several years old, and not available on PyPI. You can use yolk to [tell which versions of a package are available on PyPI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888027/python-and-pip-list-all-versions-of-a-package-thats-available). In this case, the only version currently available is 2.60.0.46.