# unable to pip install tensorflow (anymore)

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, pip

Until recently I was able to install the tensorflow 1.5.0 package when using python 3.6.7 on windows. Now I can't and from the message "from version" below it seems that no tensorflow package is available at all.

Did the support stop recently?

Some additional information taking into account the comments from micha137 and hoefling:

In linux, tensorflow is available in many flavors. This is the case with pip version 9.0.3, 10.0.1, and 18.1 I tried.

For example:

```
(env3)xxx@xxx-linux:/local/mnt/workspace/tmp$ pip install tensorflow==
Collecting tensorflow==
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow== (from versions: 0.12.0rc0, 0.12.0rc1, 0.12.0, 0.12.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0rc0, 1.1.0rc1, 1.1.0rc2, 1.1.0, 1.2.0rc0, 1.2.0rc1, 1.2.0rc2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0rc0, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0rc0, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0rc0, 1.5.0rc1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0rc0, 1.6.0rc1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0rc0, 1.7.0rc1, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0rc0, 1.8.0rc1, 1.8.0, 1.9.0rc0, 1.9.0rc1, 1.9.0rc2, 1.9.0, 1.10.0rc0, 1.10.0rc1, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.11.0rc0, 1.11.0rc1, 1.11.0rc2, 1.11.0, 1.12.0rc0, 1.12.0rc1, 1.12.0rc2, 1.12.0)
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==
(env3)xxx@xxx-linux:/local/mnt/workspace/tmp$ pip --version
pip 18.1 from /local/mnt/workspace/tmp/env3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip (python 3.4)
```

By contract, in Windows:

```
C:\tmp>pip --version
pip 18.1 from c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.6)

C:\tmp>pip install tensorflow==
Collecting tensorflow==
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow== (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==
```

Some additional information:

```
C:\tmp>pip install -vvv tensorflow. -
Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Config variable 'WITH_PYMALLOC' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Created temporary directory: C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-fmlkvkla
Created temporary directory: C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-tracker-oijk67__
Created requirements tracker 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-oijk67__'
Created temporary directory: C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tt2d7lx0
Cleaning up...
Removed build tracker 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-oijk67__'
Invalid requirement: 'tensorflow.'
```

Followed by a lengthy traceback.

And:

```
C:\tmp>python -c "from setuptools import pep425tags; print(pep425tags.get_supported()[0])"
c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\pep425tags.py:89: RuntimeWarning: Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
  warn=(impl == 'cp')):
c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\pep425tags.py:93: RuntimeWarning: Config variable 'WITH_PYMALLOC' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
  warn=(impl == 'cp')):
('cp36', 'cp36m', 'win32')
```

Comment: Please post the output of `python -c "from setuptools import pep425tags; print(pep425tags.get_supported()[0])"` and `pip install -vvv tensorflow`.

Comment: @hoefling See updated post.

Comment: Looks like you have 32bit Python installed, can you check that? `python -c "import sys; print('64 bit' if sys.maxsize > 2**32 else '32 bit')"` Tensorflow is available for 64 bit distribution only.

Comment: @hoefling THANK YOU !!!! Somehow I installed the 32-bit flavor by accident. Do you want to provide this as an answer so that I mark as approved answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the output of

```
python -c "from setuptools import pep425tags; print(pep425tags.get_supported()[0])"
('cp36', 'cp36m', 'win32')
```

you have the supported Python version, but a 32 bit distribution installed (the platform tag is `win32`; for 64 bit Python on Windows, it should be `win_amd64`). Tensorflow is available for 64 bit distributions only ([all the wheels on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#files) have platform tag either `macosx_10_11_x86_64` for MacOS, or `manylinux1_x86_64` for Linux, or `win_amd64` for Windows). Installing the 64 bit Python (e.g. from [`python-3.6.8-amd64.exe`](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.8/python-3.6.8-amd64.exe)) will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to [list the available versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888027/python-and-pip-list-all-versions-of-a-package-thats-available#26664162):

```
$ pip.exe install tensorflow==
Collecting tensorflow==
   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow== (from ver sions: 1.2.0rc2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0rc0, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0rc0, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0, 1.5.0rc0, 1.5.0rc1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0rc0, 1.6.0rc1, 1.6.0, 1.7. 0rc0, 1.7.0rc1, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0rc0, 1.8.0rc1, 1.8.0, 1.9.0rc0, 1.9.0rc1, 1.9 .0rc2, 1.9.0, 1.10.0rc0, 1.10.0rc1, 1.10.0, 1.11.0rc0, 1.11.0rc1, 1.11.0rc2, 1.11.0, 1.12.0rc0, 1.12.0rc1, 1.12.0rc2, 1.12.0)
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==
```