# Is it possible to search for when a specific version of a package has been published?

Tags: python, pip, pypi

Is it possible to search when a specific package was pushed to Pypi? i.e.

```
pip search foo==0.17 
foo (0.17) {SOME DATE}     
pip search foo==0.18 
foo (0.18) {SOME OTHER DATE}
```

I can see the release history on Pypi's page but is it available through pip? I don't want to see the version numbers, I want the date it was released.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python and pip, list all versions of a package that's available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888027/python-and-pip-list-all-versions-of-a-package-thats-available)

Comment: @RajanChauhan I don't want to list the packages, I want the date it got pushed to Pypi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. PyPI has an API with all packages information in JSON format.

Example: `https://pypi.org/pypi/{YOUR_PACKAGE}/json`

```
import json
import requests


def search(package_name, version):
    url = 'https://pypi.org/pypi/%s/json' % package_name
    response = requests.request('GET', url)
    if response.ok:
        json_response = json.loads(response.content)
        uploads = json_response['releases'][version]
        for upload in uploads:
            print('upload date %s | filename = %s' % (upload['upload_time'], upload['filename']))


search('pandas', '0.24.2')
```

Output:

```
upload date 2019-03-14T10:10:10 | filename = pandas-0.24.2-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
upload date 2019-03-14T10:10:34 | filename = pandas-0.24.2-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_i686.whl
upload date 2019-03-14T10:10:39 | filename = pandas-0.24.2-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
upload date 2019-03-14T10:10:44 | filename = pandas-0.24.2-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
upload date 2019-03-14T10:10:49 | filename = pandas-0.24.2-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
upload date 2019-03-14T10:10:55 | filename = pandas-0.24.2-cp35-cp35m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
upload date 2019-03-14T10:11:00 | filename = pandas-0.24.2-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_i686.whl
upload date 2019-03-14T10:11:05 | filename = pandas-0.24.2-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
upload date 2019-03-14T10:11:11 | filename = pandas-0.24.2-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
upload date 2019-03-14T10:11:15 | filename = pandas-0.24.2-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
upload date 2019-03-14T10:11:21 | filename = pandas-0.24.2-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
upload date 2019-03-14T10:12:12 | filename = pandas-0.24.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_i686.whl
upload date 2019-03-14T10:12:18 | filename = pandas-0.24.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
upload date 2019-03-14T10:12:23 | filename = pandas-0.24.2-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
upload date 2019-03-14T10:12:27 | filename = pandas-0.24.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
upload date 2019-03-14T10:12:33 | filename = pandas-0.24.2-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
upload date 2019-03-14T10:12:38 | filename = pandas-0.24.2-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
upload date 2019-03-14T10:12:43 | filename = pandas-0.24.2-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
upload date 2019-03-14T10:12:47 | filename = pandas-0.24.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
upload date 2019-03-14T10:12:53 | filename = pandas-0.24.2.tar.gz
```

Hope it helps!