# pip can't find a tensorflow-cpu version which is listed in pypi.python.org

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I am trying to `pip install rasa` on Ubuntu x64 in a new Python 3.6.9 virtual environment.

```
Collecting tensorflow-cpu~=1.15.0 (from rasa)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-cpu~=1.15.0 (from rasa) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow-cpu~=1.15.0 (from rasa)
```

If I `pip install tensorflow-cpu~=1.15.0` I get the same error. I also cannot `pip install tensorflow-cpu`.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40745656/458742) I can list available package versions. It uses this snippet

```
def versions(pkg_name):
    url = f'https://pypi.python.org/pypi/{pkg_name}/json'
    releases = json.loads(request.urlopen(url).read())['releases']
    return sorted(releases, key=parse_version, reverse=True)
```

Running it with `pkg_name="tensorflow-cpu"` I get

```
2.1.0
2.1.0rc2
2.1.0rc1
2.1.0rc0
1.15.0
1.15.0rc3
1.15.0rc2
1.15.0rc1
1.15.0rc0
```

But `1.15.0` is in this list. So why can't pip install it?

Comment: The [release page](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-cpu/1.15.0/#files) only listed binary wheel packages for very specific Python and OS versions.  If the platform/environment you are trying to run this installation on falls outside it, the error message will result.

Comment: There might well be a release `1.15.0` but maybe no **distribution** that matches your environment. Could you edit your question to mention details such as the version of the Python interpreter (3.X.Y), the operating system (Linux, Windows, Mac), the bitness (32 or 64 bits), etc.

Comment: @spraff 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: I mentioned x64 is the architecture.

Comment: @spraff Indeed, I missed it. My bad. Then [`tensorflow_cpu-1.15.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl`](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fa/49/e1d2c4cb1780a994be4cc11758efa180d94d08098b33b2cd52b4647b6fbe/tensorflow_cpu-1.15.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl) should fit. Not sure why _pip_ doesn't want to select it... Maybe try downloading this file and installing it directly.

Comment: Most probably you have an old distro that doesn't have `manylinux2010` compatibility, only `manylinux1` and Google dropped that recently. Run `python -c "from pip._internal.pep425tags import get_supported; print(get_supported()[0])"` to check that - if you get smth like `('cp36', 'cp36m', 'manylinux1_x86_64')`, then you're out of luck. Either upgrade the OS or stick with older tensorflow versions.

Comment: @hoefling Yes, that's the issue.