# pip 21 no longer showing available version numbers

Tags: python, pip

`pip` had a feature that showed you the available versions of a package in case you used `[package]==` instead of just the package name or `[package]==[version]`. Since the release of pip 21, this no longer works.

Here's a demonstration (Arch Linux):

```
$ mkdir pip-issue
$ cd pip-issue
$ python3.9 -m venv env
$ . env/bin/activate
$ pip list
```

Output (`stdout` and `stderr` warning):

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        20.2.3
setuptools 49.2.1
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 21.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/home/patrick/env/bin/python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.`
```

As I said, I can "query" the available versions with an older `pip` version:

```
$ pip install requests==
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests== (from versions: 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.3, 0.2.4, 0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.2, 0.3.3, 0.3.4, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.5.0, 0.5.1, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.6.2, 0.6.3, 0.6.4, 0.6.5, 0.6.6, 0.7.0, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.7.3, 0.7.4, 0.7.5, 0.7.6, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.8.3, 0.8.4, 0.8.5, 0.8.6, 0.8.7, 0.8.8, 0.8.9, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 0.9.3, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.10.2, 0.10.3, 0.10.4, 0.10.6, 0.10.7, 0.10.8, 0.11.1, 0.11.2, 0.12.0, 0.12.1, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.13.2, 0.13.3, 0.13.4, 0.13.5, 0.13.6, 0.13.7, 0.13.8, 0.13.9, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.14.2, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.3.0, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.7.0, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 2.10.0, 2.11.0, 2.11.1, 2.12.0, 2.12.1, 2.12.2, 2.12.3, 2.12.4, 2.12.5, 2.13.0, 2.14.0, 2.14.1, 2.14.2, 2.15.1, 2.16.0, 2.16.1, 2.16.2, 2.16.3, 2.16.4, 2.16.5, 2.17.0, 2.17.1, 2.17.2, 2.17.3, 2.18.0, 2.18.1, 2.18.2, 2.18.3, 2.18.4, 2.19.0, 2.19.1, 2.20.0, 2.20.1, 2.21.0, 2.22.0, 2.23.0, 2.24.0, 2.25.0, 2.25.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for requests==
```

Which allows me to parse the `stderr` output for available version numbers, which comes in handy for automatic update checks.

However, when I update `pip` (as suggested):

```
$ pip install --upgrade pip
...
Successfully installed pip-21.0
```

This no longer works:

```
$ pip install requests==
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests==
ERROR: No matching distribution found for requests==
```

Is there a work around for that, so that I can query the available versions?

Comment: Github issue https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9139 via https://stackoverflow.com/a/26664162/5320906

Comment: `pip install --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver requests==` is a workaround, but then one should ask whether upgrading `pip` to 21 was worth it at all.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue. I see a consensus that such a feature is needed in pip, but there's no consensus yet on how it should be done.

Comment: Concerning upgrading to pip21: I generally don't like to rely on old versions, because it's always a tradeoff that becomes worse as time goes.