# Pip - show versions of package

Tags: python, pip

Before [the pip resolver was changed](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9187) recently, I could easily do `pip install foo==` to find out what versions of a package were available:

```
% pip install hydra-core== --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 
hydra-core== (from versions: 0.1.4, 0.1.5rc1, 0.1.5, 0.9.0, 0.10.0, 
0.11.0rc1, 0.11.0, 0.11.1rc1, 0.11.1, 0.11.2rc1, 0.11.2, 0.11.3, 1.0.0rc1, 
1.0.0rc2, 1.0.0rc3, 1.0.0rc4, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 
1.0.6, 1.1.0.dev1, 1.1.0.dev2, 1.1.0.dev3, 1.1.0.dev4)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for hydra-core==
```

Now that doesn't work anymore:

```
% pip install hydra-core==                                 
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement hydra-core==
ERROR: No matching distribution found for hydra-core==
```

Is there some other quick way to do this?  Note that I'm not just finding packages from `pypi.org`, I have private package registries too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pip version `21.0 > x > 20.3` you can still use the same approach with a flag to explicitly use the discarded resolver:

```
pip3 install --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver hydra-core==
```

as explained in the [announcement](https://discuss.python.org/t/announcement-pip-20-3-release/5948) on python.org this flag was removed in January 2021. Now you can

```
pip install yolk3k
```

and then

```
yolk -V hydra-core
```

from my own experience, this will not always give the full list of available versions for any package. Otherwise see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888027/python-and-pip-list-all-versions-of-a-package-thats-available) old post, which was recently updated 3 days ago.