# I'm installing requirements.txt file in Pycharm but i'm getting this error what to do

Tags: python, conda

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:

Solving environment: ...working... failed


UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - aiohttp==3.7.3
  - multidict==5.1.0
  - pyrsistent==0.15.7
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Comment: Please copy-paste the text from the error, don't use a (badly-readable) image. Format the contents with a code block for better readability as well.

Comment: Obviously, you'll need to change your versions requirements. Increase or decrease your version requirements for one or more packages, or remove some version requirements altogether, to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Your `requirements.txt` file package versions for these 3 packages in the error message needs to be changed. Either these specific version do not exist or you already have a package installed with a different version.

To list available version for specific packages follow the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888027/python-and-pip-list-all-versions-of-a-package-thats-available)

** A lazy solution can be just to change these 3 lines in your `requirements.txt` file to:

```
aiohttp>=3.7.3
multidict>=5.1.0
pyrsistent>=0.15.7
```