# Pip, find latest version of package at some time in the past

Tags: python

I am currently trying to run some example code in python but I encountered some problems with backward compatibility. The file I am trying to run in python was written some three years ago, and couple of packages from back then are already out of date. I figured I will build a virtual environment and there download those specific older versions of dependencies to run the file but I struggled to find an information of what were these exact versions back then.

I did some research and I found yolk3k which lists all the previous versions of the package, but does not shows their release dates.

Also I have found an option '--before ' in pip, but also failed to use it to my benefit.

Did anyone encountered similar issue? Is there an easy way, to list all old packages with their release dates?

Comment: Normally, `pip` should automatically download older versions if a package needs older versions ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python and pip, list all versions of a package that's available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888027/python-and-pip-list-all-versions-of-a-package-thats-available)

Comment: Well not exactly. The problem is concentrated more over me finding out which version of package was latest at some point in the past. I know the versions, but can i somehow extract their release dates next to them?

Comment: This is the answer you are looking for in the dupe-target: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27239645/5769463