# How to find the list of available versions for an specific package with Poetry?

Tags: python, python-poetry

Using Poetry, I want to find all versions of an specific package that are available for install. Is it possible to achieve that?

(Similar to [Python and pip, list all versions of a package that's available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888027/python-and-pip-list-all-versions-of-a-package-thats-available))

Comment: Why do you want to use poetry for this task?

Comment: @finswimmer The version I'm current using for a specific package cannot be installed with Poetry. I want to see all versions available to see if I have an alternative version I could use.

Comment: poetry can break on some versions. e.g I cannot run `poetry add notebook` on MacOS Big Sur and curious about alternative versions available.

Answer (score 16):

It won't show all versions available, but if you want to see the latest version of a given package available for install using Poetry, you can use a combination of the `@latest` version qualifier and `--dry-run` option of `poetry add`, as follows:

```
poetry add <package>@latest --dry-run
```

This will output the version of the package (and dependent packages) available, but will not execute anything.

Answer (score 15):

To display the current and the latest version of the packages installed in your virtual env, just run the command:

```sh
poetry show --latest
```

But the `show`-command has special param for checking the outdated packages only:

```sh
poetry show --outdated
```