# Capital gains calculatation

Tags: python, django

Does any one knows older version of "capital-gains" python library. This support python3.9+ version.

Or any other python library that i can use for capital gains calculation.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just [check all available versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888027/python-and-pip-list-all-versions-of-a-package-thats-available?rq=1) in pip repository
And check [release history](https://pypi.org/project/capital-gains/#history) for `capital-gains`
After that check [release history](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/python-version-history) for python

First version of `capital-gains` released at May 2018. Same as `Python 3.7.0`

So if you using `Python 3.7.0` or newer you may install older version by using `pip install capital-gains==1.0.0` (or newer)

<sub><sup>If your python is older, [these](https://python.libhunt.com/tax-calculator-alternatives) alternatives may be useable (I don't know what is `capital-gains` and just leave google suggestion here)</sup></sub>

Comment: Thank you so much, i'll try to do this.