# How to output the latest version of a pip package?

Tags: python, shell, npm, pip, package

Similar to how we can run `npm show {package} version` to get the latest version available for any npm package, is there an equivalent command for pip/python?

I don't necessarily want to upgrade to that version, I would just like to be able to output the latest version number available for any package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command just shows the available versions of pip package, if I correctly understand your question.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip==
```

or to see any package versions:

```
pip install package_name==
```

*P.s. Yes there will be an error, that says no match)*

Comment: This is pretty clever, to get the answer without another package. You can then get the latest version with: `python -m pip install --upgrade figgypy== 2>&1 | grep "from versions:" | sed "s/^.*from versions: \(.*\))/\1/" | awk -F ", " '{print $NF}'`.

Comment: @theherk Totally agree

Comment: Wow that's crafty, that was exactly what I was looking for, thank you! This way also seems to be consistently faster than using yolk3k, aside from not needing another package as well.

Comment: Interesting edge case to look out for: if your current version of the package resolves to 0 (i.e 0.0.0, 0.0), the command `python -m pip install --upgrade {package}==` will not produce an error and therefore will not work. Potentially use `python -m pip install --upgrade {package}==-` instead to ensure the version can't be satisfied and will always produce an error.

Comment: Another edge case is that the pip error message does not contain the list of all the package versions when pip is version 21.0

Answer (score 1):

You can use [yolk3k](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yolk3k) as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5422144/2081835).

```
➜ pip install yolk3k
➜ yolk -V figgypy
figgypy 1.1.9
```

Answer (score 0):

List outdated packages with the installed and the latest versions:

```
pip list --outdated
```

See the [docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_list/#cmdoption-o).

Comment: This answer requires the package to have been installed already.  The question does not specify whether the package is already installed.