# How do I check if any of my Python dependencies have an update available?

Tags: python, pypi

I am working in a project where we've pinned all our depdencies. Eg:

```
pandas == 1.4.3
streamlit == 1.11.1
pendulum == 2.1.2
pyodbc == 4.0.34
...
```

It'd be good to write a function that will quickly check what is the latest version of each package in PyPi.

Eg:

```
def check_for_out_of_date_dependencies(pyproject_toml_filepath):
   ...

check_for_out_of_date_dependenceies()
>>> "You have pandas '1.4.3' but '1.4.4' is available"
>>> ...
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean you want the latest version? so why not use `pandas >= 1.4.3`?

Comment: use this api [pypi json api](https://warehouse.pypa.io/api-reference/json.html)

Comment: I am getting this error using the pypi json API: ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='pypi', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /pandas/json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001CCC4A4BCD0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27239645/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpypi%5D+latest+version

Comment: The URL is https://pypi.org/pypi/pandas/json : HTTPS (port 443), path `/pypi/pandas/json`

Comment: Fixed it. `requests.get('https://pypi.org/pypi/pandas/json')` works.

Comment: Also there is [_`python -m pip list --outdated`_](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_list/#cmdoption-o).