# How can pip install packages which are missing from it's index?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

According to Chris' answer (most upvotes) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888027/python-and-pip-list-all-versions-of-a-package-thats-available/26664162#26664162), `pip index versions package_name` is a reliable way to find the versions available for a given package.

But I discovered something peculiar... It seems that `pip install` **works** for packages like `tb-nightly` & `tf-nightly-macos`. Yet when I try `pip index versions tf-nightly-macos` or `pip index versions tb-nightly` then it tells me `ERROR: No matching distribution found for tb-nightly`.

How can pip download/install packages which are missing from its index? And moreover is there a partial/full fix to see package versions for all/more packages which are visible for install/download by pip?

P.S. **My default index url is:** `https://pypi.org/simple`. Also system info is: MacOS Ventura 13.4.1, M1 chips, python 3.9.13, (but likely applies elsewhere too).

Comment: This post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888027/ may help you. It’s an alternative to the command pip index versions

Comment: @RadoTheProgrammer That question you linked is the same one that I mentioned I got `pip index versions` from. Which answer were you referring to exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try: `python -m pip index versions --pre tb-nightly`.

This is an excerpt of the output for `python -m pip index versions --help`:

> `--pre` Include pre-release and development versions. By default, pip only finds stable versions.

Typically, the *nightly* suffix in distribution related topics means that it is about *pre-releases* (specifically ones that are built every night), not an official release. And indeed the versions listed by the command above seem all to have the marking of a [pre-release](https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/#pre-releases), for example `2.15.0a20231013` where the `a` means it is an *alpha* release.